# Datepicker textfield edit uneditable

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I have a DatePicker with the following code :

```
    datepicker.getEditor().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        datepicker.show();
    }
    );
```

When clicked on the textfield, the popup appears.
[Datepicker popup open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbPcU.png)

The problem is that i can't type a number in the textfield when the popup is shown.
is it a problem of focus ?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you can select a date from the popup, but you can't type anything in the textbox manually. It's `editable` problem.

In FXML, add `editable="true"` to your TextField tag. Or check the "Editable" checkbox in Scene Builder. I hope so it can help to you.

Have a nice coding :)

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't specify. It's not a HTML DatePicker, it's JavaFX.

Comment: Heam, ok. Firstly sorry, just i am trying help to you. @KeyurBhanderi your comment is nothing said to me, but thanks, you should keep it to yourself.

In FXML, add `editable="true"` to your TextField tag. Or check the "Editable" checkbox in Scene Builder.

I hope so it can help to you.

Have a nice coding :)

Comment: thanks but editable="false" is the opposite of what i want to do. I want the popup to disappear when i type something

Comment: Sorry, first i am thinking opposite, and i change my comment :) (I think i am not a good day :D )

Comment: Thanks that's what i needed

Comment: @BastienMONNET i am happy for this :) I change my answer to what is the solution. Can you mark this to a solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExampleDatePicker extends Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

private DatePicker datepicker;

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    this.datepicker = new DatePicker() {
        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            final DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = (DatePickerSkin) super.createDefaultSkin();

            datePickerSkin.getPopupContent().setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final KeyEvent ke) {
                    ExampleDatePicker.this.setText(ke.getCharacter());
                }
            });

            return datePickerSkin;
        }

    };

    this.datepicker.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        this.datepicker.show();
    });

    stackPane.getChildren().add(this.datepicker);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane, 400.0, 200.0));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public void setText(final String string) {
    this.datepicker.getEditor().setText(this.datepicker.getEditor().getText() + string);
}}
```